# Finding $P(A \cap D)$ when $P(A), P(B), P(C), P(D), P(A \cap B), P(A \cap D) + P(B \cap C)$ is known

Tags: probability

If:

$$P(A) = 0.26, P(B) = 0.39, P(C) = 0.15, P(D) = 0.20$$
$$P(A \cap B) = 0.21$$
$$P(A \cap D) + P(B \cap C) = 0.11$$

and

$$P(A \cap C) = 0$$
$$P(B \cap D) = 0$$

Is it possible to find or make an estimate for the value of $P(A \cap D)$?

I've tried it with venn diagrams and couldn't get anywhere. This is a real world problem, I would like to know if its solvable or not.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: Draw the simplest Venn diagram that has nontrivial values for the above, and see what you can manipulate while keeping the values constant.

Comment: @deinst tried that and couldn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The best one can do is to say that $0\le P(A\cap D)\le 0.05$.

From $P(A) = 0.26$ and $P(A\cap B)=0.21$ we get that $P(A\setminus B) = 0.05$, and so from $P(A\cap B)=0$ we see that $P(A\cap D)\le P(A\setminus B)=0.05$, but this is the only restriction.  Any value of $0\le x \le 0.05$ will assign the probabilities as follows.

\begin{align*}
P(D\setminus A) &= 0.20 - x\\
P(A\cap D) &= x\\
P(A\setminus(B\cup D)) &= 0.05 - x\\
P(A\cap B) &= 0.21\\
P(B\setminus(B \cup C)) &= 0.07 + x\\
P(B\cap C) &= 0.11 - x\\
P(C\setminus B) &= 0.04 + x 
\end{align*}

Intuitively, we have the venn diagram looks like a chain with $C$ and $D$ being the end links, but the area they share with the rest of the chain fixed, so if you pull one out, the other moves in.